# TypeScript: funky type inference in map()

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I made a bug today:

```js
  private maybeCreatePager(eventIssueName: Maybe<string>): Maybe<Pager<T>> {
    return eventIssueName.map(n => {
      this.issuePagers[n] = this.createPager(n);  // WRONG. n is of type string but createPager expects a Maybe<string>
      return this.issuePagers[n];
    })
  }

  private createPager(eventIssueName: Maybe<string>): Pager<T> {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }
```

However, the type catcher does not complain unless I explicitly give the type of `n`. Shouldn't it be obvious?

Here is part of my `Maybe` implementation:

```js
export abstract class Maybe<T> {

  static unit<U>(x: U) { return new Just<U>(x); }
  abstract bind<U>(f: (T) => Maybe<U>): Maybe<U>;

  map<U>(f: (T) => U): Maybe<U> {
    return this.bind(x => Maybe.unit(f(x)));
  }
}
```

Why wouldn't the type of `n` be inferred?

Comment: it would be beneficial if you created an example on Typescript playground.

Comment: `(T) => U` is [not what you intend it to be](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-dont-i-get-type-checking-for-number--string-or-t--t); try `(t: T) => U`.  Same with `(T) => Maybe<U>`.